# how can i work around path names in arcpy having spaces in them?

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

I'm trying to create an arcpy tool for one of the teams, and I have everything 
working.

But when I redirect the path names to be where their data is saved and where they want the outputs to go to, I get errors like ERROR:00732 or ERROR:00210 and its because of the folder directories having spaces in their names.

is there a work around for this?

Comment: Please add an [mcve]. It's important both in answering your question and for folks in the future with similar questions.

Comment: There's lots of Q&As about those errors at the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: could you point to somewhere in the GIS stack exchange because everything I see says use double quotes which don't make a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Have to put the path between doble quotes.

For example:

```
Path = “path/to/folder”
```